# Restrict the user to delete, rename and modify the file created using Java.in Windows

Tags: java, file-io, file-permissions, java-io

I am creating a file in Windows and want to restrict the user to delete, rename and modify the file created. I am using the below code to create the file and have given Read-only permissions. However, users are able to modify the file created.

Thanks a lot.

```
public class checkFilePermission {

      private static String path = "C:\\Users\\abc_user\\Desktop\\VI\\test123.txt";

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            checkPermissions(path);


      }


      public static void checkPermissions(String path){
            File file = new File(path);
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
            if(file.canExecute()){
                  System.out.println("Executable file");
            }
            if(file.canRead()){
                  System.out.println("Readable file");
            }
            if(file.canWrite()){
                  System.out.println("Writeable file");
            }

            //We can set the permissions as well.

            file.setExecutable(false);
            file.setReadable(false);
            file.setWritable(false);
            //file.setReadOnly();

            System.out.println("Exe = "+file.canExecute());
            System.out.println("Read = "+file.canRead());
            System.out.println("Wrt = "+file.canWrite());

      }


}
```

Comment: `file.setExecutable` etc. return boolean values to denote whether they succeeded. It would be worth checking those.

Comment: @Michael, Codebeginner needs a logic to restrict users to delete, rename or modify the file created. above code is just some trials done. checking the permissions before and after setting it. Thanks

Comment: @HiteshKumar I understood all of that. The first step in my diagnostic process would be checking the return values of those functions. They're presumably returning false, but what if they're not?

Comment: I checked: ' boolean a =  file.setExecutable(false);
   boolean b =   file.setReadable(false);
   boolean c =    file.setWritable(false);
      //file.setReadOnly();
       
   System.out.println(a +"-" +b +"-" +c);'  Result: false-false-true

Answer (score 1):

I tried below ways to restrict user to delete, rename and modify the file. Please do try the same and make it work. After providing the permissions, we have to revoke the privileges form the users

```
public static void Permissions(String path) throws IOException{
            File file1 = new File(path);
            System.out.println(file1.getPath());

              if (file1.createNewFile()){
                    System.out.println("File is created!");
                  }else{
                    System.out.println("File already exists.");
                  }
              //1. Using CACLS cmd
//            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("CACLS myfile.txt /E /G hitesh_golhani:R" + path);

                //2. Using file methods
//               boolean a =  file.setExecutable(true,true);
//               boolean b =   file.setReadable(true,true);
//               boolean c =    file.setWritable(true,true);
//               file.setReadOnly();

              //3. Using FilePermission
//            SecurityManager sm = new SecurityManager();
//            FilePermission fp1 = new FilePermission(path, "read");
//            PermissionCollection pc = fp1.newPermissionCollection();
//               pc.add(fp1);


              //4. Using POSIX java 7
//            Set perms = new HashSet();
//            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
//            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
//            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath(), perms);

              /*  //5. Using Path
              Path file = Paths.get(path);
              AclFileAttributeView aclAttr = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, AclFileAttributeView.class);
              System.out.println("owner------"+aclAttr.getOwner());
              for(AclEntry aclEntry : aclAttr.getAcl()){
                  System.out.println("entry----"+aclEntry);
              }
              System.out.println();

              UserPrincipalLookupService upls = file.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
              UserPrincipal user = upls.lookupPrincipalByName(System.getProperty("hitesh_golhani"));
              AclEntry.Builder builder = AclEntry.newBuilder();       
              builder.setPermissions( EnumSet.of(AclEntryPermission.READ_DATA, AclEntryPermission.EXECUTE, 
                      AclEntryPermission.READ_ACL, AclEntryPermission.READ_ATTRIBUTES, AclEntryPermission.READ_NAMED_ATTRS,
                      AclEntryPermission.WRITE_ACL, AclEntryPermission.DELETE
              ));
              builder.setPrincipal(user);
              builder.setType(AclEntryType.ALLOW);
              aclAttr.setAcl(Collections.singletonList(builder.build()));*/

          System.out.println("Exe = "+file1.canExecute());
          System.out.println("Read = "+file1.canRead());
          System.out.println("Wrt = "+file1.canWrite());          
    }
```

Comment: I am trying icacls command to grant/deny the permission and running the command using java.

Comment: Remove access:
   `icacls path  /remove:g  userName:(OI)(CI)F /T`         Provide read acces:
   `icacls path /grant userName:(OI)(CI)R /T`